# How to add a link inside an svg circle

Tags: html, css, svg, hyperlink

I have drawn a circle using svg. This circle has a hover effect. I would like to add a link within in the circle and for the link text to change color along with the hover effect.

```css
svg#circle {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}

circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 700;
  stroke-dashoffset: 700;
  stroke-linecap: butt;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 2s ease-out;
  transition: all 2s ease-out;
}

circle:hover {
  fill: pink;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  stroke-dasharray: 700;
  stroke-width: 10;
}
```

```html
<svg id="circle">
        <circle cx="125" cy="125" r="100" stroke="darkblue" stroke-width="3"     fill="green" />
     </svg>
```

Comment: The actual question about linking is pretty easy to answer (as below), but this use of an animated stroke-dash transitions is pretty clever and deserves an upvote :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to add a `text` element wrapped in an anchor link.

*Note, the `text` element, being on top of the `circle` will block the hover action on that circle. So, I've wrapped the whole thing in a `g` group and placed the hover capture on that instead.*

```css
svg#circle {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}
g circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 700;
  stroke-dashoffset: 700;
  stroke-linecap: butt;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 2s ease-out;
  transition: all 2s ease-out;
}
g:hover circle {
  fill: pink;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  stroke-dasharray: 700;
  stroke-width: 10;
}
text {
  fill: pink;
  font-size: 24px;
}
a:hover text {
  fill: blue;
}
```

```html
<svg id="circle">
   <g>
  <circle cx="125" cy="125" r="100" stroke="darkblue" stroke-width="3" fill="green" />
  <a xlink:href="https://www.google.co.uk/" target="_top">
    <text x="50%" y="50%" style="text-anchor: middle">google</text>
  </a>
     </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: UPDATE: SVG "xlink" tags have since been deprecated. Just replace "<a xlink:href=" with "<a href="

Answer (score 17):

I think this will work :

```html
<svg id="circle">
  <a xlink:href="https://www.google.com" style="cursor: pointer" target="_blank">
    <circle  cx="125" cy="70" r="60" stroke="darkblue" stroke-width="3" fill="green" />
  </a>
</svg>
```

**EDIT:** Dynamically adding link to SVG `Circle`.

```js
function addAnchor(){
  var dummyElement = document.createElement("div");
  dummyElement.innerHTML = '<a xlink:href="https://www.google.com" style="cursor: pointer" target="_blank"></a>';
  
  var htmlAnchorElement = dummyElement.querySelector("a");

  var circleSVG = document.getElementById("circle");

  htmlAnchorElement.innerHTML = circleSVG.innerHTML;

  circleSVG.innerHTML = dummyElement.innerHTML;
  
}
```

```html
<svg id="circle">
    <circle  cx="125" cy="70" r="60" stroke="darkblue" stroke-width="3" fill="green" />
</svg>

<button onclick="addAnchor()">Add Anchor</button>
```

Comment: How do i add this a tag using javascript?

Comment: @Vishnu It's straight forward approach manipulating `DOM` elements.  Check the edited answer. If you using `jQuery` it's quite easy. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

very simple!..

just wrap the entire SVG in a link...this worked for me anyway!!

1. initialise the link,
2. insert svg,
3. close svg,
4. close link

```html
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968082/how-to-add-a-link-inside-an-svg-circle#"> <svg style="align-self: center" height="125" width="190" </a>>
    <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
    <stop offset="3%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,0);stop-opacity:0" />
    <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1" />
    </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <ellipse cx="100" cy="70" rx="85" ry="55" fill="url(#grad1)" />
    
    <text fill="#000066" font-size="40" font-family="Verdana" x="50" y="86">MBS</text>
    Sorry, your browser does not support SVG.
    </svg> </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Very, Very Simple. Add onClick in tag element,
Using the inLine event handler.
Event handlers are not only for HTML objects, like DIV, TR, P, TABLE, etc.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

```html
<svg>
    <circle onClick="location.href='https://stackoverflow.com'" cx="50" cy="50" r="25" stroke="darkblue" stroke-width="3" fill="green" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74663537/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).