# wavy button shape with text inside

Tags: html, css, button, svg, shapes

I'm trying to create this button:

[image]

I'm doing this with SVG, so here is my code:

```css
.svg-button { 
position:relative; 

}

a.test {
  
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-button">

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="150px" height="51px" viewBox="0 0 150 51" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="Desktop-HD" transform="translate(-987.000000, -779.000000)" stroke="#102CCA">
            <g id="Group-6" transform="translate(836.000000, 668.000000)">
                <g id="Group" transform="translate(151.000000, 111.000000)">
                    <path d="M0.5,0.5 L0.5,47.4475413 C38.7946588,43.6370428 73.268313,43.6553687 103.92161,47.5038947 C134.273898,51.314629 149.5,49.8747765 149.5,43.6367187 L149.5,30.078125 C149.5,19.2695184 149.5,19.0898429 149.5,0.936176488 L0.5,0.5 Z" id="Rectangle"></path>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>

</svg>
    
    <a class="test" href="#">add to cart</a>

</div>
```

Any ideas on how I might integrate the text inside the shape and add a hover state for the shape/button?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to save your svg file and implement this   <input type="image" src="myImage.svg" alt="Submit" width="48" height="48" value="Add To cart"> and add this input inside the anchor tag

Comment: I want to be able to add a hover state for the shape and I think this is not a good approach. What do you think?

Comment: You want the text inside the shape and for that shape we need to do hover right?

Comment: Hope this helps you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968082/how-to-add-a-link-inside-an-svg-circle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could do it.

You could move the text into the SVG using a `<text>` element...

```css
a.test:hover svg path {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-button">

<a class="test" href="#">

<svg width="150px" height="51px" viewBox="0 0 150 51" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="Desktop-HD" transform="translate(-987.000000, -779.000000)" stroke="#102CCA">
            <g id="Group-6" transform="translate(836.000000, 668.000000)">
                <g id="Group" transform="translate(151.000000, 111.000000)">
                    <path d="M0.5,0.5 L0.5,47.4475413 C38.7946588,43.6370428 73.268313,43.6553687 103.92161,47.5038947 C134.273898,51.314629 149.5,49.8747765 149.5,43.6367187 L149.5,30.078125 C149.5,19.2695184 149.5,19.0898429 149.5,0.936176488 L0.5,0.5 Z" id="Rectangle"></path>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>

    <text x="75" y="27" text-anchor="middle">add to cart</text>

</svg>

</a>

</div>
```

Or if you wanted to keep the text as HTML. You could use relative/absolute positioning to centre the text over the SVG.

```css
.svg-button { 
  position: relative; 
}

.svg-button svg,
.svg-button a { 
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 51px;
  top: 0;
}

.svg-button a { 
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 45px;
}

.svg-button:hover svg path {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-button">

  <svg width="150px" height="51px" viewBox="0 0 150 51" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="Desktop-HD" transform="translate(-987.000000, -779.000000)" stroke="#102CCA">
            <g id="Group-6" transform="translate(836.000000, 668.000000)">
                <g id="Group" transform="translate(151.000000, 111.000000)">
                    <path d="M0.5,0.5 L0.5,47.4475413 C38.7946588,43.6370428 73.268313,43.6553687 103.92161,47.5038947 C134.273898,51.314629 149.5,49.8747765 149.5,43.6367187 L149.5,30.078125 C149.5,19.2695184 149.5,19.0898429 149.5,0.936176488 L0.5,0.5 Z" id="Rectangle"></path>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>

  </svg>
    
  <a class="test" href="#">add to cart</a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend grouping the svg path and the text 'add to cart' inside of the svg (with a "g" element). I'm also guessing that you want this whole button to act as the link, so I'd recommend structuring the HTML like the following:

```
<a>
  <svg>
    <g>
      <path></path>
      <text>Add to cart</text>
    </g>
  </svg>
</a>
```

...and positioning the path and the text inside of the group with x and y values. You can then target the path and the text, when the whole link is being hovered on like this:

```
a:hover svg g text {
  fill: red;
}
a:hover svg g path {
  stroke: red;
}
```

Check out this simple codepen I made for a demo and let me know if you have any questions! https://codepen.io/segheysens/pen/VzbzeJ