# how to add hyperlinks on css animated

Tags: css, animation, charts

I want to use a linear graph on my website.
I found a code on WEB and I want to use it on my website.
It's ok for me to use it in this state but I want adapt the code to add text and Hyperlinks on each point. But I don't know how to.

Does somebody can help me ?

Thanks a lot.

REGARDS.

Comment: Here's the link to CODEN code [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/JonasBadalic/pen/jvCLe).

Answer (score 0):

simply add `<a>` tag to `<circle>` element.

Here you draw the svg by js . Append `<a>` before circle element

It may helpful to you for adding hyperlink : [How to add a link inside an svg circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968082/how-to-add-a-link-inside-an-svg-circle)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer but It doesn't work. Can you help me to have a text and hyperlink (appears in the same time that the dot) ? REGARDS

Comment: Add it svg in html with svg tag and before circles give a tag

Comment: Here you draw the svg by js . Append <a> before circle element